# Jupyter Notebook - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook

I have cloned Jupyter notebook from Git repository and installed it in new separate conda environment for development purposes. I have installed correctly as given in https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.rst.

With 'jupyter notebook' command, it runs notebook in the browser, but opens up a blank page instead because of some javascript issues it is getting in browser console. They are:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined(…)check @
>   require.js?v=f960924…:900
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
>   underscore.js:15
>
> Failed to parse SourceMap:
>   http://localhost:8888/static/tree/js/built/1.main.min.js.map

I haven't modified any js code till now. I have just installed it.
How to resolve this issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is platform specific. There might be some problem on my dev-master. For windows, try following commands:

```
git log
git checkout 4.2.0
```

With these commands, you will have fresh checkout and also for webpack build. After that, try following commands:

```
python setup.py js
python setup.py css
```

This will extract all js and css dependencies. Now try:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Everything works great!

Comment: I am having the same problem and don't understand your solution very well. From where should I run `git log` ?

Comment: @BND, I ran it in a separate conda environment. This may help you: https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/